# Trying to copy regfile with PowerShell 2.0 to another folder

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to export `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI` as well as `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI` regfile with PowerShell 2.0 to another drive.

I have read [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208793/attempting-to-export-remote-registry-hive-with-powershell) but I only get error message with that code. This may be because I am using v2.0. I cannot use a higher version.

Does anyone have any idea on why it doesn't work or possible how to copy both of them to another drive using PowerShell v2.0?

**Code**

```
reg copy HKCU\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI H:\temp /s /f
```

**Error**

```
reg.exe : ERROR: Invalid key name.
At line:1 char:4
+ reg <<<<  copy HKCU\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI H:\temp /s /f
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: Invalid key name.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Type "REG COPY /?" for usage.
```

Comment: I would like a script to export/copy them to a folder called temp in network drive H: so when the user gets a new computer the user can just go into his own H: drive and open them on the new computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`reg copy`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742057.aspx) is for copying data from one registry key to another registry key, not for exporting registry keys to a file. That's what [`reg export`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742017.aspx) is for.

```
reg export HKCU\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI H:\temp\odbc_ini.reg /y
```

`reg.exe` is an external command, so the error has nothing to do with the PowerShell version.